# How to return a plain text or css file from remix route?

Tags: remix.run

Can I return a plain text file or css file from a remix route ?

e.g https://localhost:3000/my-dynamic-css

I would fetch (from API) and modify the css in my code but the response from the above url would be plain css code without html tags and js code that I can use in my other routes.

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you want is a "resource" route. This is simply a route that exports a loader or action, but does NOT export a default component.

```js
// routes/my-dynamic-css.ts

export async function loader() {
  const css = await getCss()
  return new Response(css, { headers: { 'content-type': 'text/css' } })
}
```

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/api-routes#resource-routes

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks Kiliman